# Group By Date.Date

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am struggling to do a group by. I have the following list:

```
 Date = 10/03 06:40 AM, Val = 10  
 Date = 10/03 08:55 PM, Val = 5  
 Date = 11/03 06:40 AM, Val = 5  
 Date = 11/03 10:50 AM, Val = 9  
 Date = 11/03 06:40 PM, Val = 14
```

And I want this list:

```
 Date = 10/03, Val = 5  
 Date = 11/03, Val = 14
```

So a list grouped by `Date.Date` but with Val depending on `Max(d => d.Date)`.

I did it with a `foreach` but I am pretty sure that we can do something better using LINQ (`groupby`,`select`). Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: https://morelinq.github.io/2.8/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MaxBy__2_1.htm

Comment: Define "better", why is LINQ better? A method that orders the values, then grabs the last value each date is going to be easier to understand than a convoluted LINQ query. Of course, if this is hitting a database through Entity Framework or similar then LINQ may be better but "better" is a relative term and open for both interpretation and opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want something like

```
static T MaxBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> selector)
where TKey: IComparable<TKey> =>
    source.OrderByDescending(selector).First();
```

Then

```
from item in items
group item by item.Date.Date into byDate
select new
{
    Date = byDate.Key,
    byDate.MaxBy(item => item.Date).Val
}
```

If you do not wish to create a dedicated method you can also do it inline of course

```
from item in items
group item by item.Date.Date into byDate
let ordered = from item in byDate
              orderby item.Date descending
              select item.Val
select new
{
    Date = byDate.Key,
    Val = ordered.First() 
}
```

*Note: Thanks to mjwills who pointed out a bug which I was then able to correct*

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
var result = from d in list
             group d by d.Date.Date into grouped
             let max = grouped.Max(d => d.Date)
             select new {
                 Date = grouped.Key,
                 list.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Date == max)?.Val
             };
```

Comment: I don't want the Max value of Val, I want the last value up to date. It is different :) Look at the example, for the 10/03 val is equal to 5 not 10

Answer (score 0):

Something along the line of:

```
values
    .GroupBy(value => value.Date.Date)
    .Select(grouped => new
        {
            Date = grouped.Key,
            Val = values.First(value => value.Date == grouped.Date.Max()).Val
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what i have end up with :

Example entity :

```
public class ExampleEntity
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int Val { get; set; }
}
```

Example code :

```
var listOfExampleEntity = new List<ExampleEntity>()
        {
            new ExampleEntity()
            {
                Date = new DateTime(2018, 10, 03, 3, 40, 00),
                Val =2
            },
            new ExampleEntity()
            {
                Date = new DateTime(2018, 10, 03, 4, 40, 00),
                Val =2
            },new ExampleEntity()
            {
                Date = new DateTime(2018, 11, 03, 5, 40, 00),
                Val =5
            },new ExampleEntity()
            {
                Date = new DateTime(2018, 10, 03, 3, 40, 00),
                Val =2
            },new ExampleEntity()
            {
                Date = new DateTime(2018, 11, 03, 7, 40, 00),
                Val =3
            },new ExampleEntity()
            {
                Date = new DateTime(2018, 11, 03, 8, 40, 00),
                Val =4
            },
        };

        var temp = listOfExampleEntity.GroupBy(
                    p => p.Date.Date,
                    p => p.Val,
                    (date, val) => new { Date = date, Value = val.Last() });
```

Comment: Lol just change p.Key.Month to p.Key.Date .... it will work the same way with the day .....

Comment: Your code only works if the data in the original source is in order. It also relies on `dictionary` returning data in the order you added to it (which it does as long as you never remove data, but it isn't a behaviour you can rely on).

Comment: it's just for an example you can always create model and have properties etc.... its just a simple example with dictionary for 5 min craft and it works ... Whatever, have a good day :)

Comment: That `ToList()` isn't needed.

Comment: true I have  just remove it :)